# Admin login as user in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am working on a Laravel 5.8 project. I want to make an authentication system where the admin can log in as a user. I have separate tables for authentication; one is for admin, and the second is for normal users.

User login works on the default Laravel authentication, and for admin, there is a custom code for login.

```
Auth::guard('admin')->attempt([
    'name' => $request->name,
    'password' => $request->password
], $request->remember);
```

For example:

I have 3 users:
user1
user2
user3

And one admin user with a username of "admin."

The admin can see a list of users on site. And on that page, there is a button which says "login as...". So when the admin clicks on that button, the admin can log in as that user. This means the admin can do what that user can do. But all work will be done as admin.

**In short:**
If the admin wants to log in as any of the users on front and perform his stuff, the admin will log in as that user. Meanwhile, the admin wants to log in to the front end as User1, but the admin side admin will log in as admin.

Comment: better to keep user and admin in same table with different role.

Comment: add another column in user table to make administrable the user, so when the admin switch to user this value change to true and this can be used together with a middleware or a policy in routes...just thinking! ;-)

Comment: I think there is a i can not explain good in my question. If admin want to login as any of the user on front and perform his stuffs. Means meanwhile admin want to login on front end as User1 but on admin side admin will login as admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead. You can add 2 table columns, maybe one called "role" with enum values, e.g., ADMIN, CUSTOMER, and another called "is_normal_user" with boolean type values, which you can set to true or false. So when you try to login as admin and perform admin functions, use the role by checking if their role is ADMIN or CUSTOMER, then when you try to log in and do customer functions as the admin, use the "is_normal_user" field.

Comment: I think there is a i can not explain good in my question. If admin want to login as any of the user on front and perform his stuffs. Means meanwhile admin want to login on front end as User1 but on admin side admin will login as admin.